# Image as Background in Shopify

Tags: css, shopify

Having a bit of an issue adding an image as a background to a Shopify site. I would like to include picture footer_lodyas.png as a background image but am having difficulty. This is where I am at right now:

```
// Backgrounds
$colorBody: {{ settings.color_body_bg }};
$body.background-class {
    background-image: url({{'footer_lodyas.png' | asset_url }});
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
$colorHeader: {{ settings.color_header_bg }};
$colorTopBar: {{ settings.color_topbar_bg }};
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Has the css file the extension liquid? As in styles.css.liquid?
Otherwise the "asset_url" won't work

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need quotes around the asset url, otherwise there will be a syntax error in sass or css: `background-image: url('{{'footer_lodyas.png' | asset_url }});`. And the extension should be `.scss.liquid` because you have sass variables